# Learning C# and I have a casting question

Tags: c#, types, casting

W3 schools provides the following code:

```
double myDouble = 9.78;
int myInt = (int) myDouble;    // Manual casting: double to int

Console.WriteLine(myDouble);   // Outputs 9.78
Console.WriteLine(myInt);      // Outputs 9
```

On line 2, if I have already declared that the variable type is 'int', why must I also cast myDouble as an integer when I have already declared it to be one?

I see the same thing in the book I am using, where the line reads:

```
float num1 = (float) 20.9;
decimal num2 = (decimal) 20.9;
```

Again, we're putting the data type in parentheses after we've already told it to use that specific data type. I am SURE that there is a reason on the backend, I simply do not know what it is.

Comment: the TLDR is: to tell the compiler you know what you are doing when using a conversion that may result in data loss.

Comment: Without this you could chase a weird defect forever and not know why the value of `myInt` isn't what you expect. If you know that there's a conversion you can look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#:~:text=Implicit%20numeric%20conversions,-The%20following%20table&text=Any%20integral%20numeric%20type%20is,the%20double%20and%20decimal%20types.) and understand exactly how it gets converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are understanding it wrong.

First any point number in c# is handled as a double, if you don't tell the compiler to not do it.

So if you do this:

`int number = 20.5`

you are

1. Declaring a variable `number` of type `int`
2. Assigning to it a value of type `double`

this will not work. Here will not work since you cannot store `doubles` in `ints`...

If you do like this

`int number = (int) 20.5` will work, but you are casting your `double` to `int` so `number` will be `20` and not `20.5`.

> On line 2, if I have already declared that the variable type is 'int', why must I also cast myDouble as an integer when I have already declared it to be one?

No you don't. You declared the variable of type `int` but the value you are trying to assign to it is not of type `int` but `double` so you need it to convert to `int` before you can assign to it.

In your second example you have the same story...

Your numbers there, you are trying to assign are of type `double` (like I said before), so you need to cast them to `float` and `decimal` before assigning them to the variables.

You could instead do:

`float myFloat = 20.5f`

See the `f`? This way you are telling the compiler you want this number to be handled as a float and not as a double, so here you don't need to cast.

I encourage you to read and learn  the different data types and the diffences between them (memory size, ranges, etc.) you can really get into big problems if not, like this one....

[A space error: $370 million for an integer overflow](https://hownot2code.com/2016/09/02/a-space-error-370-million-for-an-integer-overflow/)

Comment: I appreciate this. I'm just venturing into this and something wasn't clicking. Thanks for clearing it up.